# How can I start my Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse to develop an android application . But, now i can't open my eclipse. Error  information is "jvm terminated.  exit code = -1" . What should I do to open my eclipse?

Comment: first) there is log in <eclipse home>/configuration and <workspace>/.metadata/.log. Check what is in these files. second) please explain your situation bit more: did you change something, new version of eclipse, or jdk, what OS, 32bit or 64bit, does it work if you use another workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am OK by editing eclipse.ini .  This is out of memory exception in eclipse.
Before editing, my eclipse.ini is

```
-showsplash  
org.eclipse.platform  
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize  
64M  
-framework  
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar  
-vmargs  
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5  
-Xms40m  
-Xmx512m
```

Then I changed it like that

```
-showsplash  
org.eclipse.platform  
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize  
64M  
-framework  
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar  
-vmargs  
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5  
-Xms40m  
-Xmx256m
```

Eclipse default memory settings (at least for Eclipse 3.2) is to run with the following memory settings specified in its eclipse.ini file:

```
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m
```

Comment: I have tried to solve my own question and then I got a solution . So , I answer my own question. And thanks a lot to all of you for your attention to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the Java JDK 32 bit, and also 64 bit if you are running on a 64 bit system. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I have to try to reinstall Java JDK 64 bit.

Comment: Good luck in the future downvoting all posts. And welcome to Stackoverflow. Enjoy your stay.

Comment: Then please answer your own question so that people in the future will be helped as well.

Comment: now I answer my own question and I deeply thanks  you for answering my question.